# Can't work with multiple jQuery dataTable in one page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have a view that contains two tables in a page.

```
<table class="projectReq-table" id="FN-requirement-list">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th>No.</th>
               <th>Requirement</th>
           </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         @{var counterFN = 0;}
         @foreach (var item in Model.FunctionalRequirements)
         {
              <tr id="@item.RequirementSequence">
                  <td class="tdFN-requirement-number">@(++counterFN)</td>
                  <td class="tdFN requirement-sentence">@item.RequirementSentence</td>
              </tr>
         }
     </tbody>
</table>

<table class="projectReq-table" id="NF-requirement-list">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th>No.</th>
               <th>Requirement</th>
           </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         @{var counterNF = 0;}
         @foreach (var item in Model.NonFunctionalRequirements)
         {
              <tr id="@item.RequirementSequence">
                  <td class="tdNF-requirement-number">@(++counterNF)</td>
                  <td class="tdNF-requirement-sentence">@item.RequirementSentence</td>
              </tr>
         }
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to use the feature of the jQuery dataTables to drag-n-drop the row to another position. But it only works for the table with id `FN-requirement-list`. This is my script of the dataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FN-requirement-list').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "asStripClasses": null,
        "columns": [
            null,
            null,
            {
                "data": "item",
                "defaultContent": ""
            }
        ]
    })
        .rowReordering({
            sURL: '@Url.Action("UpdateSequence", "Requirement", new { ot = "fn" })'
        });

    $('#NF-requirement-list').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "asStripClasses": null,
        "columns": [
            null,
            null,
            {
                "data": "item",
                "defaultContent": ""
            }
        ]
    })
        .rowReordering({
            sURL: '@Url.Action("UpdateSequence", "Requirement", new { ot = "nf" })'
        });
});
```

Each `.rowReordering` function calls the function `UpdateSequence` in the `RequirementController` but with a different parameter as you can see `fn` and `nf`. This is the UpdateSequence function in the RequirementController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateSequence(int id, int fromPosition, int toPosition, string direction, string ot)
{
    ...
}
```

I've already traced the parameter passed to the function and it only works for the first table, id `FN-requirement-list`.

For example when I drag the second row of the `FN-requirement-list` table to the first row and it sends the parameter to the function

```
id = 2
fromPosition = 2
toPosition = 1
direction = back
ot = fn
```

But when I try the same thing with the `NF-requirement-list` table and it sends the parameter to the function like this

```
id = 2
fromPosition = 2
toPosition = 2
direction = back
ot = nf
```

It doesn't work for the `NF-requirement-list` table, no `toPosition` passed to the function.

How am I supposed to do to fix this? I've heard the issue that one page can't use multiple jQuery datatables, but I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: code looks fine, check and compare the number of columns in result and in html side, in such a case there wont be any error message,it just wont work

Comment: I've also already see the rendered html, but it is fine. Any other ideas?